# Placing <td> under with inline styles (email)

Tags: html, css, email, html-table, html-email

I am styling an email signature using table and I have encountered a problem on mobile devices.

On mobile the text is squashed and I would like for the right image to be below the first one and the text. Using flex it would be made with flex-wrap, but I cannot use it here since I don't think it would be supported in emails.

The HTML is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table
            style="
                font-family: Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
                border-color: transparent;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                table-layout: fixed;
                overflow-wrap: normal;
            "
        >
            <tr>
                <td
                    rowspan="6"
                    style="
                        padding-right: 10px;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        width: 130px;
                    "
                >
                    <img
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"
                        alt=""
                        width="130"
                        height="130"
                    />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="color: #237; font-weight: 600; font-size: 20px"
                        >Ing. Jan Novák</span
                    >
                </td>
                <td
                    rowspan="6"
                    style="
                        padding-left: 30px;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        width: 130px;
                    "
                >
                    <img
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"
                        alt=""
                        width="130"
                        height="130"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="color: #5d6d7f">ředitel FOOBAR a.s.</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table
                        style="
                            border: none;
                            border-color: transparent;
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            table-layout: fixed;
                        "
                    >
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: #5d6d7f">Mobil: </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a
                                    href="tel:+420123456789"
                                    style="
                                        color: #237;
                                        text-decoration: none;
                                        font-weight: 600;
                                    "
                                    >+420 123 456 789</a
                                >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: #5d6d7f">E-mail: </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a
                                    href="mailto:novak@foobar.com"
                                    style="color: #237; text-decoration: none"
                                    >novak@foobar.com</a
                                >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: #5d6d7f">Web: </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a
                                    href="https://foobar.com"
                                    style="color: #237; text-decoration: none"
                                    >foobar.com</a
                                >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a
                        href="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
                        download
                        style="color: #5d6d7f; font-size: 12px"
                        >Vizitka ke stažení</a
                    >
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: A table is not your best option in that case. You should take a look at [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) layout, as well as [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Thomas Unfortunately cannot use them when styling emails, I think neither of those would be supported in them. Plus the styles have to be inline.

Comment: According to [caniemail](https://www.caniemail.com/) none of those are supported in Outlook on Windows, which is essential to work in my case, unfortunately.

Comment: What email program are you inserting the signature into? Outlook on windows?

Comment: @Nathan Sending has to work from Outlook on Windows and Gmail in browser. Supporting other platforms (Apple Mail) is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which is not complete in all details, but shows you where you can go. To see the changing result for larger and smaller screens, change the snippet result to "full page" mode, which shows the desktop version, as opposed to the mobile version in the small snippet window.

I used media queries which switch view at 800px width, but adjust that as you like.

The main thing I did is to hide and show the third cell and a second (actually fifth) row containing *one*  cell that has the same contents as the third cell/column in desktop view. I did that by copying the code of that `td` into a newly created additional `tr` and applying classes to both, which are addressed by the CSS.

Additional note: You first and third cell should only have `rowspan="4"`(not 6), since there is a nested table in the third row of the second column which counts as *one*  row for the first and third row.

I hope that explanation is clear enough ;-)

```css
.x {
  display: table-cell;
}

.y {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .x {
    display: none;
  }
  .y {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .y > td {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <table style="
                font-family: Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
                border-color: transparent;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                table-layout: fixed;
                overflow-wrap: normal;
            ">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" style="
                        padding-right: 10px;
                        vertical-align: top;
                        width: 130px;
                    ">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130" alt="" width="130" height="130" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <span style="color: #237; font-weight: 600; font-size: 20px">Ing. Jan Novák</span
                    >
                </td>
                <td class="x"
                    rowspan="4"
                    style="
                        padding-left: 30px;
                        vertical-align: top;
                        width: 130px;
                    "
                >
                    <img
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"
                        alt=""
                        width="130"
                        height="130"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="color: #5d6d7f">ředitel FOOBAR a.s.</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="
                            border: none;
                            border-color: transparent;
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            table-layout: fixed;
                        ">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span style="color: #5d6d7f">Mobil: </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="tel:+420123456789" style="
                                        color: #237;
                                        text-decoration: none;
                                        font-weight: 600;
                                    ">+420 123 456 789</a
                                >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: #5d6d7f">E-mail: </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a
                                    href="mailto:novak@foobar.com"
                                    style="color: #237; text-decoration: none"
                                    >novak@foobar.com</a
                                >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: #5d6d7f">Web: </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a
                                    href="https://foobar.com"
                                    style="color: #237; text-decoration: none"
                                    >foobar.com</a
                                >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a
                        href="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
                        download
                        style="color: #5d6d7f; font-size: 12px"
                        >Vizitka ke stažení</a
                    >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="y">
             <td 
                    colspan="2"
                    rowspan="4"
                    style="
                        padding-left: 30px;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        width: 130px;
                    "
                >
                    <img
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"
                        alt=""
                        width="130"
                        height="130"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Has this been tested in Outlook/Gmail? I'm not sure `<style>` blocks are supported at all

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, mobile Gmail doesn't seem to support `@media` queries. Just tested it.

Comment: Then you could turn it around, using a mobile first approach, using the media queries for the desktop version, which will be ignored on browsers that don't understand media queries.

Comment: @DanielNýdrle media queries are supported in mobile Gmail (apps not browser). Your style should be without errors. Gmail considers a space between `max-width:480px` right and `max-width: 480px` wrong. Just saying.

Comment: @Syfer But we're talking about inserting an email signature, so I'm not so sure about that statement.

Comment: @Nathan Sorry which statement make sense? Using media query in Gmail app?

Comment: @Syfer "Media queries are supported in mobile Gmail (apps not browser)" -- but is that still the case when you insert a *signature* via the interface, rather than sending via an ESP?

Comment: @Nathan yes you are right. Signatures using media queries through interface will not work.